# The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.i am getting Emails from Database

Tags: model-view-controller

this is method
               #region StuDetailsMail
        public List StuDetailsMail(string Stu_Name, string Stu_Email, string Stu_Mobile)
        {
            List data = new List();
        SqlParameter[] sqlprm = new SqlParameter[3];
        SqlDataReader dr = null;
        try {

```
        sqlprm[0] = new SqlParameter(DBProcedures.sqlparam_Name, Stu_Name);
        sqlprm[1] = new SqlParameter(DBProcedures.sqlpram_Email, Stu_Email);
        sqlprm[2] = new SqlParameter(DBProcedures.sqlpram_Mobile_Num, Stu_Mobile);


        dr = objDAL.ExecuteReader(DBProcedures.Usp_StuEmail, ref sqlprm, false);
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            InstEmails list1 = new InstEmails()
            {

                Emaillist = dr["email"].ToString(),

            };
            data.Add(list1);
        };

        foreach (var emailId in data)
        {

            string MessageBody = "studentname" + Stu_Name + " is Intersted" + "studentmail is" + Stu_Email;
            string MailSubject = "this is from Traininghubs";
            obj.SendEmailToInstitute(emailId.ToString(), MessageBody, MailSubject);
        }

    }






        catch(Exception e)
      {



        }



    return data;
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: am sending emails , but am getting expection The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.i am getting Emails from Database

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. While debugging check what is the value you are getting in emailid in for loop